# System of differential equations with t on one side

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I got this system
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
dx/dt+6x-5y-t=0 \\ 
dy/dt+5x-4y-1=0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

which leads to:
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
(D+6)x-5y-t=0 \\ 
(D-4)y+5x-1=0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

I multiplied top one by $(D-4)$ and bottom one by $5$ to cancel out ys.
In result I got 
$$
(D+1)^2x=(D-4)t+5
$$
Using repeated root formula, $Xc=c_1e^{-t}+c_2te^{-t}$

Now my problem starts. What should I do with $Dt-4t+5$. All examples in book have something like $e^t$ or $t^2$, which is easy to take derivative of. In my case, would it just be $-4t + 5 + C$?

If so, would trial particular solution be $Xp=At+B$? Do I just ignore "C"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(D+1)^2x=(D-4)t+5$$
$$ (D+1)^2x=1-4t+5$$
So we have
$$\implies (D+1)^2x=-4t+6$$

Try this as particular solution
$$x_h=At+B$$
$$(D+1)^2(At+B)=-4t+6$$
$$\implies At +2A+B=-4t+6$$
Solve the system to get A and B

Note that the constant C appears when you integrate not when you differentiate...

Comment: I meant that if I differentiate 't' I will be left with some constant. Wasn't sure if I should just forget about it or not.

Comment: @Kolcek2384  $$D(t)=1$$ $$D(t^2)=2t$$ $$D(e^t)=e^t$$ I added 1

Comment: You sure it's 13 ??? For A you are right and the general solution is ok @Kolcek2384

Comment: OK I see it now. Guess it's getting late. So $x(t)=c_1e^{-t}+c_2te^{-t}-4t+14$. Will let know if I have some more problems.

Comment: @Kolcek2384 Did you correct the value of the constant B ? your A is correct

Comment: It lookks good to me ..@Kolcek2384

Comment: Seems like easiest way to solve for y would be to use first equation $Dx+6x-5y-t=0$. So $y=\frac{Dx+6x-t}{5}$. $Dx=-c_1e^{-t}+c_2e^{-t}-c_2te^{-t}-4$. In this case $$y=c_1e^{-t}+c_2te^{-t}+\frac{1}{5}c_2e^{-t}-5t+16 $$

Comment: Yes thats the best way....@Kolcek2384

Comment: I couldn't solve it without extra nudge in the right direction. Thanks a lot!

Comment: you're welcome @Kolcek2384